# How to declare an enum inside a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, syntax, enums, compiler-errors, namespaces

I am able to declare an `enum` inside a nested `namespace`. But unable to do so inside a `class`.

```
namespace N {
  namespace NN {
    enum { ONE };  // OK
  }
}

namespace N {
  class C {
    public enum { ONE };  // Error: ';' expected
  }
}
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not directly supported, you can use declaration merging to achieve a similar effect, you can merge a namespace with a class declaration:

```
class C {

}
namespace C {
    export enum OtherEnum { ONE };  // OK
}

C.OtherEnum.ONE // ok
```

Or you can use a self executing function, but the syntax is uglier:

```
class C {
    public static readonly MyEnum = (function() {  enum MyEnum { ONE } return MyEnum })();
}
C.MyEnum.ONE;
```

Comment: 1st syntax looks good. Now that means the `OtherEnum` cannot be a member of `class C`. Is there any way to achieve that? Probably we have to go via dummy `interface` and then implement into a class.

Comment: @iammilind the 1st approach the enum would be static always, the second one allows you to make it an instance enum. Although I am not sure what the use case for this it. Are you sure you don't just need an enum value as a member ? (`enum OtherEnum { ONE }; class C { value: OtherEnum } `